# How to handle BackButton in SplitView's pane when DisplayMode is CompactOverlay in UWP(It works for CompactInline. Possible UWP SplitView bug)?

Tags: c#, uwp, back-button, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I know how to handle BackButton in UWP, `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;` This works fine, until I use the SplitView. I have some control which has two parts inside the SplitView's pane. When I'm inside the second part and press BackButton, I should be navigated to the first part, this works fine when I set `SplitView.DisplayMode` to `CompactInline`, however, when I set it to `CompactOverlay` after press BackButton, the pane just closed automatically without triggering the `OnBackRequested` event.  I don't know if this is intended or a bug. This only happens in  `PlatformType.WindowsMobile`. I'm wondering how can I get control of the BackButton when pane is open and in the CompactOverlay mode. Thanks!

Comment: This is by design. *Back* action should close the overlay once it's open.

Comment: @JustinXL I can understand the design purpose. But in my situation I really need to snatch this Back event from framework, and I do believe there are many situations that in mobile device, there is need to display subcategories, any work around? Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a repo for this and share?

Comment: @JustinXL I used CompactInline and handled some other events by myself.